# How to Get the title of a custom field?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I know how to get the value of a custom field, using code like `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'company', true);`. Is there a way to get the name of the custom field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get a post custom fields name you can use [**get_post_custom**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)

eg:

```
$post_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
foreach ( $post_meta as $key => $value )
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
```

this will print a list of custom_field_name => custom_field_value

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to get the name, you can use [get_post_custom_keys](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys)

```
<?php

  $custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys();
  foreach ( $custom_field_keys as $key => $value ) {
    $valuet = trim($value);
      if ( '_' == $valuet{0} )
      continue;
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

prints something like this:

```
0 => mykey
1 => yourkey
```

Comment: I just hope an explanation was given by that `(-1)` down vote..

Comment: Fail to see what's wrong with this answer, +1 from me to cancel out the downvote.